# How to tell if an MQTT payload was sent to a Basic Ingest topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

Our MQTT payloads are sent to an SQS queue using a select similar to:

```
SELECT encode(*, 'base64') AS encodedPayload, topic() AS topic, timestamp() AS receivedAt FROM 'meter/#'
```

How can I tell if the payload was sent using Basic Ingest by targeting a topic like $aws/rules/MeterIngestion/meter/<device_id> vs just sent to meter/<device_id>?

I'm hoping there is an additional field I can add to the SELECT statement.